# How to insert records into variables from cte in oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure in which I want to fetch all records from cte into  Names  variable. But this code is not writing into names from CTE. How can I fetch records into names so that I can later loop through names and get content of field_name?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_market
IS
    Names VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    WITH CTE(sqql) As 
    (
      SELECT   field_name sqql FROM   pld_medicare_config  
    )  
    SELECT sqql into Names   from CTE;      
END sp_market;
```

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT sqql into Names   from CTE;

You are assigning multiple rows returned from table to a variable, which will fail.

You could simply use a **CURSOR FOR LOOP** which will create an implicit cursor and you can loop through the names:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_market IS
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (
        SELECT field_name
        FROM pld_medicare_config
        ) 
    LOOP
        -- Your logic goes here
        dbms_output.put_line(i.field_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to create a associative array and use `BULK COLLECT` to populate the table.  In its simplest form, the code would look like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_market IS
  TYPE lt_names IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  l_tNames lt_names;
BEGIN
  SELECT field_name
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_tNames
  FROM pld_medicare_config

  IF l_tNames.COUNT() > 0 THEN
    FOR i IN l_tNames.FIRST..l_tNames.LAST LOOP
      NULL; --REPLACE WITH YOUR LOGIC
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

A few notes:

- I'm assuming that you've set MAX_STRING_SIZE to EXTENDED. Otherwise, you'll have an issue with `VARCHAR2` that big.
- As I said, that is the simplest way to do this.  If you're expecting a huge result set, you'll want to look into chunking it up.  This Oracle blog post is very helpful in giving  you multiple options for how to perform bulk processing. ([Blog Post](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall))