# VARCHAR2(32767) not able to handle strings in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am concatenating string using cursor (to form query to execute later). Here, the query that will be formed is going to be way bigger that what  VARCHAR2(32767) can handle. There fore, I am getting error on proc execution -  ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small.

I used CLOB data type as well bu got error ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error.

My code is here below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_Market
IS
   Names VARCHAR2(32767);    
BEGIN
   DECLARE CURSOR cur IS  ('Select ID, Order_of, field_name  
   FROM   pld_medicare_config');
   BEGIN       
   FOR i IN cur
       LOOP
           Names := Names ||  i.sqql;
       END LOOP;    
   dbms_output.put_line(Names);
   END;   
END sp_Market;
```

How can I handle my string of queries and what data type is there to accomplish the task?

Comment: Is this question in continuation to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/61144754/3989608 You haven't come back there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLOB` is OK (as far as I can tell); I doubt queries you store in there are *that* big.

Remove `dbms_output.put_line` call from the procedure; I suspect it is the one that raises the error.

Comment: Is there a way for me to see the content of Names  once I remove dbms_output.put_line from proc.

Comment: Yes. SELECT it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CLOB` datatype and append data using the `dbms_lob.writeappend` procedure. [This is the reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_LOB.html#GUID-BAF92526-B7D8-4FCC-B58A-1E503DA2FDC9) (Oracle 18c).

The error probably origins with the `dbms_output.put_line` call. The procedure is defined for `varchar2` arguments only which means that an implicit conversion takes place during the call. It will fail for clob contents longer than 32767 chars/bytes.

Alternatively you may declare a collection over `varchar2(4000)` and fill the collection elements sequentially:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_Market
IS
   TYPE tLongString IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   cNames  tLongString;    
BEGIN
   DECLARE CURSOR cur IS Select ID, Order_of, field_name, sqql FROM pld_medicare_config;
   BEGIN       
   FOR i IN cur
       LOOP
           cNames(cNames.COUNT+1) := i.sqql;
       END LOOP;    
   END;   
END sp_Market;
```

***Note***

Rectified code, will compile now.

Comment: That won't compile. `cur` needs to be static SQL statement, not a string (and not in brackets), and `sqql` is undefined and the assignment to it is missing a semicolon.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks for pointing out the missing ';' and the cursor issue. The code has not been tested. I shall delete this answer and sort it out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got any runtime error, as your procedure won't compile.

The valid PL/SQL version would look something like this:

```
create or replace procedure sp_market is
    names varchar2(32767);
begin
    for r in (
        select id, order_of, field_name
        from   pld_medicare_config
    )
    loop
        names := names || ' ' || r.field_name;
    end loop;

    names := ltrim(names);

    dbms_output.put_line(names);
end sp_market;
```

If `names` needs to be longer, change the datatype to `clob`.